# Microsoft Progress Bar Control is missing

Tags: windows-7, excel, progress-bar, excel-2010, vba

I need to create the progress bar on a user form. For inserting progress bar, opened toolbox , right clicked on it and choose “Additional Controls”. (Alternatively, I could go up to the “Tools”/”Additional Controls” menu). But in that list of components, “Microsoft Progress Bar Control 6.0 (SP4)” is missing. I am using Microsoft Office 2010 and Windows 7. Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two suggestions :)

**1)** Search your pc for MSCOMCTL.Ocx. If you find it then register it by clicking on Windows Start Button ~~> Run and then typing this text and pressing Enter

```
regsvr32 C:\Windows\System32\MSCOMCTL.Ocx
```

I am assuming that the ocx is in C:\Windows\System32

If you don't have that then please download it from [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896559) and then repeat the above steps.

Once done, you will now be able to use the control.

**2)** Please see this link. Sometimes you don't need a progressbar control ;)

**Topic: VBA - Working with Scroll Bars - The most simplest way**

**Link**: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=511916

HTH

Sid

Comment: @ Rout : Thanks. But it shows "The module ...ocx failed to load" while registering mscomctl.ocx. I downloaded it from http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproappcompat/thread/19b11adb-4f89-4ced-a049-1f08f2eebcd7

Comment: Downloaded http://activex.microsoft.com/controls/vb6/mscomctl.cab from also. Then extrated. Right clicked on inf and installed. Now .ocx is in system32 folder. But still having problem.

Comment: First things first :) Is your system 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: Yes There is a solution. Can we meet in say 2 hours? Was stepping out for sometime?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a makeshift loading bar whit any of the controlls you allready got, by simply useing width.

Example would be useing a label inside a frame, the frame will work as borders for it, so the top and left can be 0, then the total lenght of the frame works as max length for the label.. i think by now you see where im going whit this, basicly now all you gota do is come up whit a counter basicly a loop that counts up to max frame length :)

But, like i said whit creativity, you can use buttons, the form itself, scrollbar basicly contains itself if you dont mind it beeing a unclickable (scroll) button moveing across.