# Pop up the Excel Statusbar?

Tags: vba, excel, statusbar, excel-2010

I'm developing an application for excel that takes a long time to run so it would be nice to have a progress bar pop up and give some indication of the progress. I was looking at the `Statusbar` property in Excel and it seems to cover what I need except that it's not very obvious i.e. it's a tiny little notice in the bottom left that had I not been expecting I wouldn't have noticed which I find quite unsatisfactory.

Is there a way to have the status bar pop up in a new `MsgBox` style window similar to what you might expect with a file transfer on windows? A progress bar type object actually displayed in the excel sheet like in [this example](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/211736) is not ideal and I'm looking for a better solution.

I'm using Office 2010 on Windows.

Comment: Can you explain more why the example you're pointing will not work for you ?

Comment: @Boud when i said "wont work for me" i meant i dont want to use that method not that i actually cant. ill change that to be less confusing

Comment: @Jacxel: What kind of progress bar are you looking for? Also if you can show your code where you want to apply it then I can give you several examples...

Comment: @SiddharthRout just a generic one like [this](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC46037.png) but it doesn't have to be exactly like that. I `don't` want one that's embedded in the sheet, or the default status bar that is just a small notification in the bottom left of the window. Ideally i would like something the same as a message box that pops up with a progress bar embedded and disappears when its done. My code is just a loop I dont see how it would be relevant, I understand how the statusbar mechanism works, im asking if there is a different way to do it.

Comment: Yes there are so many ways to create a progress bar. Depending on your "taste" ;), you might want to show an animated PIE progress bar (0% to 100%) in a pop up. I think I might have an example for you that I created many years ago based on `Stephen Bullen's PastePicture code` :) Let me know if you want to have a look?

Comment: The style of the status bar doesn't bother me just so long as its obvious that its there, that's the gripe i have with the default statusbar, its barely noticeable. I would be interested in any solutions

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I just created 4 progress bars for you. Take your pick :)

The pie progressbar is based on `Stephen Bullen's PastePicture code`. Rest of the progressbar are easy to create. I have attached a sample file in the end which you can download and test.

**FEW SNAPSHOTS**

[image]

[image]

[image]

**CODE**

*In the Userform*

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, l As Long, m As Long

    j = 0: k = 0: l = 500: m = 100

    For i = 1 To 11
        '~~> Pie Progressbar Stephen Bullen's PastePicture Function
        Sheets("Sheet2").Shapes(i).CopyPicture
        Set Me.Image1.Picture = PastePicture(xlPicture)
        Me.Caption = "Progress - " & j & " %"

        '~~> 2nd Progressbar
        Label1.Width = k
        Label1.BackColor = &HFF8080
        TextBox1.Text = j & " %"

        '~~> 3rd Progressbar
        Select Case j
            Case 10: CommandButton1.Visible = True
            Case 20: CommandButton2.Visible = True
            Case 30: CommandButton3.Visible = True
            Case 40: CommandButton4.Visible = True
            Case 50: CommandButton5.Visible = True
            Case 60: CommandButton6.Visible = True
            Case 70: CommandButton7.Visible = True
            Case 80: CommandButton8.Visible = True
            Case 90: CommandButton9.Visible = True
            Case 100: CommandButton10.Visible = True
        End Select

        '~~> 4th Progressbar (Reverse)
        Label2.Width = l
        Label2.BackColor = &HC000&
        TextBox2.Text = m & " % Left"

        Wait 5

        j = j + 10: k = k + 50
        l = l - 50: m = m - 10
    Next i

    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub Wait(ByVal nSec As Long)
    nSec = nSec + Timer
    While nSec > Timer
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

*In a Module (Stephen Bullen's PastePicture Function)*

```
Option Explicit

'***************************************************************************
'*
'* MODULE NAME:     Paste Picture
'* AUTHOR & DATE:   STEPHEN BULLEN, Office Automation Ltd
'*                  15 November 1998
'*
'* CONTACT:         Stephen@oaltd.co.uk
'* WEB SITE:        http://www.oaltd.co.uk
'*
'* DESCRIPTION:     Creates a standard Picture object from whatever is on the clipboard.
'*                  This object can then be assigned to (for example) and Image control
'*                  on a userform.  The PastePicture function takes an optional argument of
'*                  the picture type - xlBitmap or xlPicture.
'*
'*                  The code requires a reference to the "OLE Automation" type library
'*
'*                  The code in this module has been derived from a number of sources
'*                  discovered on MSDN.
'*
'*                  To use it, just copy this module into your project, then you can use:
'*                      Set Image1.Picture = PastePicture(xlPicture)
'*                  to paste a picture of whatever is on the clipboard into a standard image control.
'*
'* PROCEDURES:
'*   PastePicture   The entry point for the routine
'*   CreatePicture  Private function to convert a bitmap or metafile handle to an OLE reference
'*   fnOLEError     Get the error text for an OLE error code
'***************************************************************************

Option Compare Text

''' User-Defined Types for API Calls

'Declare a UDT to store a GUID for the IPicture OLE Interface
Private Type GUID
    Data1 As Long
    Data2 As Integer
    Data3 As Integer
    Data4(0 To 7) As Byte
End Type

'Declare a UDT to store the bitmap information
Private Type uPicDesc
    Size As Long
    Type As Long
    hPic As Long
    hPal As Long
End Type

'''Windows API Function Declarations

'Does the clipboard contain a bitmap/metafile?
Private Declare Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Integer) As Long

'Open the clipboard to read
Private Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long

'Get a pointer to the bitmap/metafile
Private Declare Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Integer) As Long

'Close the clipboard
Private Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long

'Convert the handle into an OLE IPicture interface.
Private Declare Function OleCreatePictureIndirect Lib "olepro32.dll" (PicDesc As uPicDesc, RefIID As GUID, ByVal fPictureOwnsHandle As Long, IPic As IPicture) As Long

'Create our own copy of the metafile, so it doesn't get wiped out by subsequent clipboard updates.
Declare Function CopyEnhMetaFile Lib "gdi32" Alias "CopyEnhMetaFileA" (ByVal hemfSrc As Long, ByVal lpszFile As String) As Long

'Create our own copy of the bitmap, so it doesn't get wiped out by subsequent clipboard updates.
Declare Function CopyImage Lib "user32" (ByVal handle As Long, ByVal un1 As Long, ByVal n1 As Long, ByVal n2 As Long, ByVal un2 As Long) As Long

'The API format types we're interested in
Const CF_BITMAP = 2
Const CF_PALETTE = 9
Const CF_ENHMETAFILE = 14
Const IMAGE_BITMAP = 0
Const LR_COPYRETURNORG = &H4

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''' Subroutine: PastePicture
'''
''' Purpose:    Get a Picture object showing whatever's on the clipboard.
'''
''' Arguments:  lXlPicType - The type of picture to create.  Can be one of:
'''                          xlPicture to create a metafile (default)
'''                          xlBitmap to create a bitmap
'''
''' Date        Developer           Action
''' --------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' 30 Oct 98   Stephen Bullen      Created
''' 15 Nov 98   Stephen Bullen      Updated to create our own copies of the clipboard images
'''

Function PastePicture(Optional lXlPicType As Long = xlPicture) As IPicture

'Some pointers
Dim h As Long, hPicAvail As Long, hPtr As Long, hPal As Long, lPicType As Long, hCopy As Long

'Convert the type of picture requested from the xl constant to the API constant
lPicType = IIf(lXlPicType = xlBitmap, CF_BITMAP, CF_ENHMETAFILE)

'Check if the clipboard contains the required format
hPicAvail = IsClipboardFormatAvailable(lPicType)

If hPicAvail <> 0 Then
    'Get access to the clipboard
    h = OpenClipboard(0&)

    If h > 0 Then
        'Get a handle to the image data
        hPtr = GetClipboardData(lPicType)

        'Create our own copy of the image on the clipboard, in the appropriate format.
        If lPicType = CF_BITMAP Then
            hCopy = CopyImage(hPtr, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_COPYRETURNORG)
        Else
            hCopy = CopyEnhMetaFile(hPtr, vbNullString)
        End If

        'Release the clipboard to other programs
        h = CloseClipboard

        'If we got a handle to the image, convert it into a Picture object and return it
        If hPtr <> 0 Then Set PastePicture = CreatePicture(hCopy, 0, lPicType)
    End If
End If

End Function


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''' Subroutine: CreatePicture
'''
''' Purpose:    Converts a image (and palette) handle into a Picture object.
'''
'''             Requires a reference to the "OLE Automation" type library
'''
''' Arguments:  None
'''
''' Date        Developer           Action
''' --------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' 30 Oct 98  Stephen Bullen      Created
'''

Private Function CreatePicture(ByVal hPic As Long, ByVal hPal As Long, ByVal lPicType) As IPicture

' IPicture requires a reference to "OLE Automation"
Dim r As Long, uPicInfo As uPicDesc, IID_IDispatch As GUID, IPic As IPicture

'OLE Picture types
Const PICTYPE_BITMAP = 1
Const PICTYPE_ENHMETAFILE = 4

' Create the Interface GUID (for the IPicture interface)
With IID_IDispatch
    .Data1 = &H7BF80980
    .Data2 = &HBF32
    .Data3 = &H101A
    .Data4(0) = &H8B
    .Data4(1) = &HBB
    .Data4(2) = &H0
    .Data4(3) = &HAA
    .Data4(4) = &H0
    .Data4(5) = &H30
    .Data4(6) = &HC
    .Data4(7) = &HAB
End With

' Fill uPicInfo with necessary parts.
With uPicInfo
    .Size = Len(uPicInfo)                                                   ' Length of structure.
    .Type = IIf(lPicType = CF_BITMAP, PICTYPE_BITMAP, PICTYPE_ENHMETAFILE)  ' Type of Picture
    .hPic = hPic                                                            ' Handle to image.
    .hPal = IIf(lPicType = CF_BITMAP, hPal, 0)                              ' Handle to palette (if bitmap).
End With

' Create the Picture object.
r = OleCreatePictureIndirect(uPicInfo, IID_IDispatch, True, IPic)

' If an error occured, show the description
If r <> 0 Then Debug.Print "Create Picture: " & fnOLEError(r)

' Return the new Picture object.
Set CreatePicture = IPic

End Function

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''' Subroutine: fnOLEError
'''
''' Purpose:    Gets the message text for standard OLE errors
'''
''' Arguments:  None
'''
''' Date        Developer           Action
''' --------------------------------------------------------------------------
''' 30 Oct 98   Stephen Bullen      Created
'''

Private Function fnOLEError(lErrNum As Long) As String

'OLECreatePictureIndirect return values
Const E_ABORT = &H80004004
Const E_ACCESSDENIED = &H80070005
Const E_FAIL = &H80004005
Const E_HANDLE = &H80070006
Const E_INVALIDARG = &H80070057
Const E_NOINTERFACE = &H80004002
Const E_NOTIMPL = &H80004001
Const E_OUTOFMEMORY = &H8007000E
Const E_POINTER = &H80004003
Const E_UNEXPECTED = &H8000FFFF
Const S_OK = &H0

Select Case lErrNum
Case E_ABORT
    fnOLEError = " Aborted"
Case E_ACCESSDENIED
    fnOLEError = " Access Denied"
Case E_FAIL
    fnOLEError = " General Failure"
Case E_HANDLE
    fnOLEError = " Bad/Missing Handle"
Case E_INVALIDARG
    fnOLEError = " Invalid Argument"
Case E_NOINTERFACE
    fnOLEError = " No Interface"
Case E_NOTIMPL
    fnOLEError = " Not Implemented"
Case E_OUTOFMEMORY
    fnOLEError = " Out of Memory"
Case E_POINTER
    fnOLEError = " Invalid Pointer"
Case E_UNEXPECTED
    fnOLEError = " Unknown Error"
Case S_OK
    fnOLEError = " Success!"
End Select

End Function
```

**SAMPLE FILE**

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5k9f79yewqehdup/progressbar%20example.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I was trying to locate something like that on-line for quite some time and failed to find it.

Comment: Gr8 :) BTW, out of curiosity, do let me know which one of them did you finally opt in for? ;)

Comment: +1 Good one! I didn't know we could do these things in excel :)

Comment: Why not use the standard ProgressBar control?

Comment: @Cutter: Because if you distribute the Excel file to a user who doesn't have `MSCOMCTL.Ocx` then your App will give you an error. See this link :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9374715/microsoft-progress-bar-control-is-missing

Comment: Can you help explain to me how and where to enter this code in VBA. I'm brand new to VBA and was able to create a userform, but from there was lost...any help you can give would be fabulous... PS This looks very exciting to use. Have created an indexed spreadsheet that takes 20-30 seconds to process so this will come in very handy.

Comment: The link to sample file is mentioned in the post above. It has all the code that you need

Comment: This is awesome.  Anyone aware of updates to this code for 64 bit systems?

Comment: @Andrew: I haven't tested it but I guess it should work with 64 bit systems with slight modifications to the APIs. Jan Karel Pieterse's site is the best place to get the 64 bit versions of the above APIs. Here is the link to get started. http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/apideclarations.asp

Comment: ++ this is an exceptional answer