# Excel vba progressbar not working

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to follow a simple vba progressbar tutorial but its not working how it should be.

this is the [tutorial link](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=411)

I don't understand step 4 & 5, also the progress code doesn't really make sense with to goal of the progress bar, or am i wrong?

My goal is to set some references in my code, that add progress in the bar.
- How to add those references? And how to make the progressbar see it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Both urls might be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11511500/creating-a-progress-bar-in-excel-vba and http://www.learnexcelmacro.com/2012/02/progressbar-in-excel-vba/

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info, ill read it

Comment: So i read the articles, but i'd like to make the progress bar of the tutorial i found work now. I prefer it, because it has 2 bars, just what i need.

Answer (score 1):

The MS progress bar isn't available by default. By adding a reference to Common Controls, you make the progress bar available.  That's what steps 4 and 5 do.

First, delete the code in the PROGRESS section, start with For M... and ending with Unload Me.  You want this part to run from within your code and it's kind of a silly tutorial to have it run inside this event.  So delete it.

Next, the userform has a ShowModal property. This property must be set to False. Showing nonmodal means that your code will continue to run while the userform is visible.

Presumably you have two loops in your code.  Inside those loops, you need to set the value of the progress bars.  Before the loops, call the ShowForm procedure.  Inside the loops, set the values like

```
Userform1.Progress1 = M
Userform1.Progress2 = N
```

After the loops, kill the userform.

```
Unload Userform1
```

The tutorial has two loops in the Activate event just for demonstration purposes. But you want the loops in your code to drive the values of the progress bars. It's hard to be more specific without seeing your code.