# Resource image files for VBA?

Tags: image, vba, excel, ms-word

I have a word doc that I have been writing some VBA for, and in it I use this a lot:

```
LoadPicture(ThisDocument.Path & "image_name")
```

However, for this to work I've needed users to have an "Images" folder in the same directory, which is very inconvenient.

Is there a better way to include resources in a VBA project?

Thanks!

Comment: Not that I am aware of but you can store the images in a worksheet if that helps?

Comment: I've thought about this, but I'm actually not terribly sure how I would implement it. It's a word doc. Is there some way to hide a bunch of images on pages, and access them through VBA?

Comment: I have just the right sample for you :) See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782394/pop-up-the-excel-statusbar The pie charts are images which are stored in the worksheet. There is also a downloadable file in that link.

Comment: In an image control on a hidden userform?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Why not check if the folder exists on document open and create the folder if it does not?

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
    Dim imagesFolder As String

    imagesFolder = ThisDocument.Path & "\images\"
    If Len(Dir(imagesFolder, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then MkDir imagesFolder

End Sub
```

Comment: Creating the folder wouldn't help, because the folder still wouldn't have all the images in it.

Answer (score 0):

I use the QuickParts in Word to store them.  Create a new document template, paste the image onto the page and select it.  Then go to QuickParts and Add it to the Library and save your template.  Repeat for each item to add.  Then use VBA code to apply the template to the document and your QuickPart will pull in from the template.  Then use a second macro to pull your image from the QuickPart.