# progressbar without loop

Tags: excel, vba

I think I've searched the whole internet for a simple progressbar, but I can't find one that makes progress after a function/sub is finished.

I will demonstrate in the code below what I want. My knowledge in VBA is to basic too make something like this.

I have a form, with a button, when I click on the button he should execute this:

```
Sub program()

progressbarform.show

Call function1
"set progressbar to 20%"

Call funcion2
"set progressbar to 40%"

Call function3
"set progressbar to 100%"

"Unload progressbar form"

End Sub
```

Comment: See if you can adjust one of the existing code solutions to fit your needs -- [Pop up the Excel Statusbar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782394/pop-up-the-excel-statusbar)

Comment: Call function1 : ProgressBar1.Value = 25 Call function2 : ProgressBar1.Value = 40 etc.

Comment: I already tried that, but doesn't work, maybe im doing it wrong

Comment: You are calling your functions after you opened the form which takes focus, see my answer and let me know what you think :)

Comment: Check out [Progress Meters](http://www.andypope.info/vba/pmeter.htm) for an example on how to use the on a worksheet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use delegation to make this work. Your progress bar is in a separate form to your execution of function 1, 2 and 3 so you should try and execute within the progress bar form. After you call form.Show the form has focus and function 1,2 and 3 won't run until the form closes.

In your progress bar form (assuming it has a label and a progress bar control) place a function that will update your progress bar:

```
Public Sub UpdateProgress(intProgress As Integer, Optional strMessage As String)

    If Not IsMissing(strMessage) Then
        lbl_Progress.Caption = strMessage
    End If
    pb_Progress.Value = intProgress
    Call Me.Repaint

End Sub
```

Then you can execute your functions from within your progressbar form. You can do this by setting the form that called it as an object to expose your functions or just store function 1,2 and 3 in your progress bar form.

```
Sub RunFunctions()

    UpdateProgress 0, "Starting functions"    

    UpdateProgress 10, "Begin function1"    
    Call function1
    UpdateProgress 30, "Finished function1"  

    UpdateProgress 50, "Begin function2"    
    Call function2
    UpdateProgress 70, "Finished function2"  

    UpdateProgress 90, "Begin function3"    
    Call function3
    UpdateProgress 100, "Finished function3"

    UpdateProgress 100, "Finished All Functions"

End Sub
```

Ask me any questions if you need help setting this up.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, im going to try it right away. Ill comment when i need help

Comment: i get an error on UpdateProgress0 , sub or fucntion not defined, but i pasted the function code in the same userform

Comment: It's my code pasting badly, there were no spaces between UpdateProgress and the integer, try it now.

Comment: One more question.. If i want to update a progress IN another module IN a function, how to do it?

Comment: nvm i found it. Just add "userFrom1.Update..."

Comment: Correct! You can also use events to raise a control update from another form. This is if you want to be super flexible with the controls you are udpating with regards to who is calling the update. For your solution though I think it should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub program()

UserForm1.ProgressBar1.Min = 0
UserForm1.ProgressBar1.Max = 100
UserForm1.ProgressBar1.Value = 0

UserForm1.Show vbModeless

Call function1
UserForm1.ProgressBar1.Value = 20

Call funcion2
UserForm1.ProgressBar1.Value = 40

Call function3
UserForm1.ProgressBar1.Value = 100

End Sub
```

Comment: Calling `UserForm1.Show` in the same function that then calls the `function1,2,3` and repaints won't work as the UserForm1.Show takes the focus of the execution and `Call function1` that follows it won't execute until you close or hide `UserForm1`.

Comment: @Blue: yes you are right so i edited the answer and added vbModeless argument to Show :-).

Comment: That's better now that you have it as modeless. In Excel VBA this would simply be UserForm1.Show False . +1 :)

Comment: @Blue: Yes it will work with 'False' as well, but to use the constant is more accurate and code is more obvious. Show method has one optional parameter 'modal' which can be vbModal or vbModeless (VBA.FormShowConstants enum). If we use 'False' then implicit conversion converts 'False' to '0' which is equeal to vbModeless. But UserForm1.Show True won't work, because 'True' is converted to '-1' and this is not equal to vbModal. But modal is by default so Show needn't be called with 'True' ... which will fail. So i gues that to use the value named by the constatnt is better.

Comment: However in VBA for some versions of Excel there isn't vbModal or vbModeless constant. Then you need to use the False flag which is optional and defaults to True if not included. If a constant isn't consistent throughout versions the code may not work on other computers with different Excel / Office versions too. Edit: [Social MSDN Page showing users having issues with 2010 for not encluding the enumeration](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exceldev/thread/4c7e8427-e247-49dc-98bf-d562829d88cf)

Comment: @Blue: Which versions exactly? I know that vbModeless is in Excel since version 2000. But event though to use UserForm1.Show False is not correct anyway. If the constant doesn't exist then UserForm1.Show 0 would be better choice i think.

Comment: @Blue: I didn't know that in Excel 2010 such problems exist. Thanks for the info!

Comment: It has known issues in 2010. [MrExcel Thread about the issue](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/589729-environ-username-compile-error-excel-2010-a.html#post2917915) shows this well. You can use any boolean value to determine if the UserForm is modal or modeless, be that False, 0 or the VBA.FormShowConstants. However using VBA.FormShowConstants means it won't work in 2010. Using 0 instead of False is completely flexible to personal preference, however when something asks for a boolean value, I find it is best to use a boolean and not an integer to keep it consistent and explicit.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26270/discussion-between-blue-and-daniel-dusek)

Answer (score 1):

Your example code would work.

When you execute your sub, the code is run in order. So when `function1` is called the code below will not execute before `function1` has completed and the same goes for all your other functions.

The biggest problem is probably going to be getting a progress bar control onto your form. I tried (very quickly) and it would not let me add one due to the library not being registered.

You could create a fake progress bar, using the standard controls.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether my answer is helpful or not, but I made progress bar working in my main vba which I don't have any loops. Hope this can help.

I think in order to use Userform you have to put something here to active the userform first,  so probar-----(the name of the second sub) is here to active this userform. code as per below:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

progbar

End Sub
```

The second sub is completely empty with only sub and end sub, I put it in Module 1 which is blank module.

```
Sub probar()
' leave this macro blank.

End Sub
```

lastly, in you main vba, you can choose what is the percentage and how long you want to display your bar, in stead of loop you just change the percentage and bar length by yourself, put your code in between these percentage and that is how i make it work.

```
Public Sub Mainprogram()

'your code Part 1 blah blah blah

UserForm1.Text.Caption = "10% Completed"
UserForm1.bar.Width = 20
UserForm1.Show vbModeless
DoEvents

'your code Part 2 blah blah blah

UserForm1.Text.Caption = "50 % Completed"
UserForm1.bar.Width = 100
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
DoEvents

'your code Part 3 blah blah blah

UserForm1.Text.Caption = "100 % Completed"
UserForm1.bar.Width = 200
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
DoEvents

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a form with 2 `Labels`, the first in the color of your progress the other with the xx%

Now in every step your script progresses change the width of the two `Labels` so the left `Label` becomes wider and the right `Label`s Left position shifts with the same amount of pixes and update the Caption fo the second Label. Keep enough space to the right when you reach 100% in the left `Label`

Comment: Good idea, i understand it but im not sure i can program it

Comment: can you be specific in where you are stuck?

Comment: I would try and tend away from using labels when you have a progress bar control available.

Comment: Blue, I for one don't have that control in the list, is it a default one? what is it called?

Comment: You right click on the controls box or go to Tools>Additional Controls. You can find it under Microsoft `ProgressBar Control, version 6.0`. It uses MsComCtl.ocx as a reference which is available on all Pc's with Office 2000 and later.

Comment: AH now I see `Microsoft ProgressBar Control, version x.x`

Comment: You can find so many useful controls that just aren't referenced by default. ListView is a personal favourite. So much more flexible for handling dynamic data than a List/ComboBox.