# Updating an Excel Userform does not work

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a progress bar with vba to visualize the progress of my code. Therefore, I created a simple userform called PB which contains among other things 2 labels. The lenght of those labels is being changed a lot of times to show the progress of the code. My problem is that I want the resize those labels, but the change is not visible. There are some more labels which are renamed some times, but I have the same problem there as well.

So here is my shortened code which only shows the lines that refer to the userform PB.

This code is in a standard module and contains the sub Start which is the starting point for my process:

```
Public Sub Start()  
  PB.Show 
  PB.Label2.Width = 100 
  PB.Label5.Width = 100 
  PB.Caption = "Please wait, files are being analyzed!" 'Header of the userform
  PB.Label7.Caption = "Testing" 
  PB.Repaint 
  DoEvents 
End Sub
```

There is only little code inside the module of the userform PB:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate() 
  Label2.Width = 0 
  Label5.Width = 0 
End Sub
```

There are only 2 lines, but those changes to the width = 0 are executed. When this sub is finished, the rest of the start sub is executed. The width of 100 is assigned to the labels, some more labels are renamed, but these changes keep invisible.

As you see, I tried to use Repaint and DoEvents, but it didn't help in my case. I need to find a way to manipulate the userform from an external module (not the module of the userform). You can help me? Do you have an idea?

Comment: Not an answer to your question but an alternative.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782394/pop-up-the-excel-statusbar/10787496#10787496

Comment: Thanks for this link, but I already used another sample on my own. The sample worked, but when I tried to use parts of that code, it didn't work anymore. See my answer below to my question where I explained how I got it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late replay, but I didn't want to leave my question unanswered. I found a way or maybe the reason why my changes to the userform have not been shown.

Previously, as shown in my question, I have a sub Start() which is initiated when a button (a user form) is klicked. The Start()-sub then initiates the my userform which is called "PB". 
So it's this order:

1. Button (user form) calls
2. Start()-sub which then calls
3. PB-userform

I found only two differences in the sample from which I take the code. I changed the button to an Active-X control and the following order:

1. Button (Active-X) calls
2. PB-Userform calls
3. Start()-sub.

Code of the button:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
  PB2.Show
End Sub
```

Code of the PB-userform:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
  Label2.Width = 0
  Label5.Width = 0
  Call Main.Start
End Sub
```

Now, all changes of the Start()-sub are visible and executed at "DoEvents". Of course, "PB.Show" inside the Start()-sub is needless since the PB-userform is already visible.

For me, the main change is that the Start()-sub is called by the userform. I can't explain why it's necessary to call the userform first, but somehow is feels like the userform now has the "control" or something like that. Maybe someone else can explain this.

EDIT:
Last Update: I found the reason why the userform didn't update when I tried it as described in my question. To keep it short:

```
PB.Show vbmodeless
```

So there is an option for the show-method. Without "vbmodeless" the form waits for a user action/input. But with the option "vbmodeless" the form runs for itself. If you want to know more, check the VBA help of show.