# Adding a progress bar to macro in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VERY simple macro that ties a refresh to a button.  All it does is I click the button, and it refreshes all external connections (xml and web) in the workbook.  However, I'm trying to add either a progress bar or a status message in the message bar.

Right now it's simple:

```
Sub refreshAll()
    ActiveWorkbook.refreshAll
End Sub
```

It does what it's supposed to, now I just want some way of telling how far along it is (and getting the process to run in the background.  I'd like to change this to something that counts how many connections there are, then goes through and refreshes each connection while counting it out in the status bar.

Such as:  "15 of 300 finished 20%"

And it just simply counts as it goes through them updating the bar as it goes.  I don't know if there is a way to update the bar using the refreshAll, or if i have to loop through and refresh them counting as it goes.  Any ideas?

EDIT:

I have it working for the most part:

```
Sub refreshAll()

    Dim con As String
    Dim cLen As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim pInt As Double
    Dim percent As String
    cLen = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.count
    i = 0

    Do
        con = "Connection" & i
        pInt = i / cLen
        percent = FormatPercent(pInt, 0)
        ActiveWorkbook.Connections(con).Refresh
        Application.StatusBar = "Updated " & i & " of " & cLen & " | " & percent & " Complete"
        i = i + 1
    Loop While i < cLen
    Application.StatusBar = "Update Finished"

End Sub
```

The problem is that everything works as it should, it counts the correct number of connections, and in the status bar it prints like it should but it zips through in a second without actually updating any of the connections.  If I go hit the "Refresh All" button it takes about 15 seconds to refresh the data, if I click the button I created it just zips through without refreshing.

Comment: You will have to use the `Workbook.Connections` property.

Comment: You will have to loop through the connections and refresh them. And if you want them to look jazzy then you might want to use [THESE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782394/pop-up-the-excel-statusbar/10787496#10787496) progressbars :)

Comment: Ok, I started with it, but it's breaking down right from the get go, please see edits.

Comment: `Clen` is not an object. It is a variable. remove the word `Set` before it

Comment: Ok, check out the new edit to see what's not working now.

Comment: I also added ActiveWorkbook.Connections(Connection0).Refresh to the macro, it's giving me a Run-time error '9': String out of range even though the connection is named Connection0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off `Enable background refresh` in `Data > Connections` for each connection. Also, try using a `For`-loop rather than a `Do-While` loop (see following code).

```
Sub RefreshAll()

    Dim con As String
    Dim cLen As Long
    Dim Iter As Long
    Dim pInt As Double
    Dim percent As String
    cLen = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count - 1

    For Iter = 0 To cLen
        con = "Connection" & Iter
        pInt = Iter / (cLen + 1)
        percent = FormatPercent(pInt, 0)
        ActiveWorkbook.Connections(con).Refresh
        Application.StatusBar = "Updated " & Iter & " of " & (cLen + 1) & " | " & percent & " Complete"
    Next Iter

    Application.StatusBar = "Update Finished"

End Sub
```

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: It should be `1 to cLen`, I think. And you'd want to refer to `ActiveWorkbook.Connections(Iter)`.

Comment: @DougGlancy: I'm just going by OP's post here, but I think `Connections(con)` works if you have the name of the connection passed in. Also, he did say he had a connection named `Connections0`. ;)

Comment: I recommend not just going by the OP's post. For one thing `0 to Connections.Count` will iterate one more time than there are connections. For example, `0 to 5` yields six iterations, which will clearly fail when there are only 5 connections. I'm going to downvote for now.

Comment: I added a variable to subtract 1 from the total to make the for loop work, I also went through and disabled background refresh on each connection 1 by 1, it's still not working though, I get the exact same behavior as before. btw, @Doug-Glancy the connection is named connection0-however many connections there are.  so putting Iter in there will only try to use a connection named whatever number you are on, the connection##.  So even though this doesn't fix it, I'm upvoting since he at least tried.

Comment: well, with the help of @BK201 I've arrived at almost a complete solution.  The macro is complete and now it's just a matter of figuring out why the data isn't refreshing.

Comment: Corrected the cLen issue. I should have seen that starting at 0 should entail one less on the upperbound. I've created some connections on my end and this is working (the default MSDN connections). I'll have to test some more as to why the ones on your end are not updating. I don't want to believe that simple xml and web connections behave like this on VBA.

Comment: This might be trivial, but I've tried every kind of refresh on my end so... 1) Are you sure it should be `ActiveWorkbook`? 2) Are there special permissions or issues needed on your end to access these data? 3) Please check case sensitivity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not clear on your connection-naming scheme. This will update all connections in the workbook, using an index to step through them. The status bar is updated. I moved the message to before the update, as that human eyes are more likely to see it:

```
Sub RefreshAllConnections()
Dim con As String
Dim cLen As Long
Dim Iter As Long
Dim pInt As Double
Dim percent As String
cLen = ActiveWorkbook.Connections.Count

For Iter = 1 To cLen
    pInt = Iter / cLen
    percent = FormatPercent(pInt, 0)
    With ActiveWorkbook.Connections(Iter)
       Application.StatusBar = "Updating " & Iter & " of " & cLen & " | " & percent & " Complete"
        .Refresh
    End With
Next Iter

Application.StatusBar = False
End Sub
```

Comment: it's the default connection name...  I didn't name it that way, when I created the connections it named them connection followed by connection1 - the last connection, i simply named the first connection connection0 to make it easier to deal with.  I'll give this a shot though, maybe it'll fix my refresh issue.

Comment: Ok so I tried yours, same result as I and @BK201 already came up with.  I don't think the issue is in our coding, for some reason ActiveWorkbook.Connectionx(x).Refresh doesn't actually refresh the connection

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Be sure to let us know if you figure it out.