# VBA Progress bar based on fix duration

Tags: excel, progress-bar, duration, vba

How can I adjust this progress bar macro to represent the duration of the code, knowing that the total time to execute the code is 50 secondes? I'm using VBA7.

```
Sub ShowUserForm()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
Sub Main()
    Dim Counter As Integer
    Dim RowMax As Integer, ColMax As Integer
    Dim r As Integer, c As Integer
    Dim PctDone As Single

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Initialize variables.
    Counter = 1
    RowMax = 100
    ColMax = 100

    ' Loop through cells.
    For r = 1 To RowMax
        For c = 1 To ColMax
            'Put a random number in a cell
            Cells(r, c) = Int(Rnd * 1000)
            Counter = Counter + 1
        Next c

        ' Update the percentage completed.
        PctDone = Counter / (RowMax * ColMax)

        ' Call subroutine that updates the progress bar.
        UpdateProgressBar PctDone
    Next r
    ' The task is finished, so unload the UserForm.
    Unload UserForm1
End Sub

Sub UpdateProgressBar(PctDone As Single)
    With UserForm1

        ' Update the Caption property of the Frame control.
        .FrameProgress.Caption = Format(PctDone, "0%")

        ' Widen the Label control.
        .LabelProgress.Width = PctDone * _
            (.FrameProgress.Width - 10)
    End With

    ' The DoEvents allows the UserForm to update.
    DoEvents
End Sub
```

Comment: it's not a good idea, because on different machines you will have different execution time

Comment: I agree with @simoco: Don't base your PBar on predefined time. Also on a side note you may want to see [THIs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782394/pop-up-the-excel-statusbar/10787496#10787496) and simply update the PBar in between your code... Say something like 10% done... 20% done... etc?

Comment: Yes, I know it's not the best idea to use a fix execution time, I'll try your link @Siddharth Rout thanks!

Comment: At best, what you can do is time to see (at run time) how long it's been for 10% of the code (computational-time-wise) to complete, for e.g. and then show 9x that number as time remaining, and re-measure again at every 10% milestone to readjust your estimate. That's the cleanest way to give the best estimated time.