# How do you populate imagelist with shape from worksheet?

Tags: vba, excel, treeview, imagelist

I wish to create a Treeview with images and data from a worksheet (each line has the name of a part, its next up assembly and an icon all populated by the user). I've finally managed to get the treeview to populate correctly and to include images from an external source (based on code from various sources and just a little of my own).
Setting up the Imagelist and assigning it to the Treeview is still a mystery to me but it works.

What is missing is getting the pictures from inside the worksheet and into the Imagelist instead of from an outside source ((using `iml.ListImages.Add 1, "img1", LoadPicture("C:\Temp\red.jpg")` ).
I read dozens of posts about it to no avail, and there is one that is mentioned in several places but is a deadend. The one other alternative I've read about involves copying the picture to the clipboard and pasting elsewhere but it involves a lot of code and seemed beyond my capability, so I haven't tried it yet.

I can "read" the pictures properties from the worksheet using `Sheet1.Shapes(1)` or similar with `.Type` (which results in "13") or `.Name` (which returns "Picture 1" for example) or `.TopLeftCell.Address` (which returns "$C$1" for example) etc. So I know I have access to them and am referencing the correct objects.

When I try to use `iml.ListImages.Add 1, "img1", Sheet1.Shapes(1)` I get a "Invalid Picture" error.

When I try to use `iml.ListImages.Add 1, "img1", Sheet1.Shapes(1).Picture` I get a "Object doesn't support this property or method" error.

When I try to use `iml.ListImages.Add 1, "img1", Sheet1.Shapes(1).CopyPicture` I get a "Type Mismatch" error.

I don't know what else to try and where else to look. Please help.

EDIT:
All this happens within a userform.

Comment: `The one other alternative I've read about involves copying the picture to the clipboard and pasting elsewhere but it involves a lot of code and seemed beyond my capability, so I haven't tried it yet.` Save the image to the user's temp drive and then load it from there. Do a search on the net on how to export the image. You will find a lot of examples

Comment: @SiddharthRout I think there might be a better way to go. Check my answer.

Comment: @CaptainABC: `1.` Better in what way? :) `2`. Also the images are in the worksheet. In your answer below, how are you loading the images to the image control specifically when they are in the worksheet :) UNLESS you are using `Stephen Bullen's PastePicture code` as shown [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782394/pop-up-the-excel-statusbar/10787496#10787496)

Comment: CaptainABC's approach requires I load the pictures at design time, but that is not possible because the users will populate the workheet with their own images and data afterwards.

Comment: Siddrath's approach should work (I'll still have to learn alot about saving the images but the information is out there). I'm affraid that when the number of nodes and consequently pictures go into the hundreds (as I'm sure they will) it may become too slow or unstable. Any comments on this aspect? It would alsobe much more elegante if it could be done "internally", but that is just nice to have.

Comment: Is there really no way to coax the picture from the Shape object?
On a side note: MS "help" pages on VBA are useless in that bring no humanly understandable information unless you already know it and they seem incomplete in that other people always tell you more than they do about their own objects etc.

Comment: @PauloMiguelPeixotoMendonça: No it will not be slow or unstable :) See the link in the 2nd comment above. It is pretty fast :). [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25521950/select-chart-within-userform/25523186#25523186) is another example based on that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SiddhartRout provided the alternative that worked in a comment above: "Stephen Bullen's PastePicture code" as shown [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782394/pop-up-the-excel-statusbar/10787496#10787496). It's the only alternative I found that would not require going outside the file and it worked fine (on a sample file; still pending testing on a bigger example).
Thank you all for the help.

I would like to upload the file with the code etc. but I don't know how to do it, so I'm pasting the part of the "heart" of the code. There are two more modules: one to call the userform and Stephen Bullen's module. The code below is added to the userform itself, and it contains the treeview, the "OK" button and two images called "RED" and "GREEN" which are just small square jpgs of the respective color. I hope this helps.

```
' based on macros written 19991217 by Ole P. Erlandsen, ope@erlandsendata.no
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Integer, strNodes As String, lngSelCount As Long
Me.Hide
lngSelCount = 0
strNodes = "Checked Items" & Chr(13) & "Index, Key, Text:" & Chr(13)
For i = 1 To TreeView1.Nodes.Count
    With TreeView1.Nodes(i)
        If .Checked Then
            strNodes = strNodes & .Index & "; " & .Key & "; " & .Text & "; " & .Image & Chr(13)
            lngSelCount = lngSelCount + 1
        End If
    End With
Next i
strNodes = strNodes & Chr(13) & "Count of Checked Items: " & lngSelCount
strNodes = strNodes & Chr(13) & Chr(13) & _
    "Selected Item" & Chr(13) & "Index, Key, Text:" & Chr(13)
With TreeView1.SelectedItem
    strNodes = strNodes & .Index & "; " & .Key & "; " & .Text & "; " & .Image & Chr(13)
End With
MsgBox strNodes, , "TreeView1 Output"
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'Author: Paulo Mendonça 02/September/2014 ppmendonca@hotmail.com

Dim oNode, oParent As Node
Dim oCell As Range
Dim oShape As Shape
Dim iml As ImageList
Dim oImage, oSheet, oDataColumn As String
Dim oParentColumnOffset, oImageColumnOffset, oInitialDataRow As Integer
Dim oFound As Boolean

oSheet = "Sheet2"
oDataColumn = "A"
oInitialDataRow = 2
oImageColumnOffset = 2
oParentColumnOffset = 1

'create new ImagList and populate it
Set iml = New ImageList
'iml.ImageHeight = 256
'iml.ImageWidth = 256
iml.ListImages.Add 1, "red", RED.Picture 'defined in UserForm1 and set to invisible
iml.ListImages.Add 2, "green", GREEN.Picture 'defined in UserForm1 and set to invisible
For Each oShape In Sheets(oSheet).Shapes 'look up every shape in the sheet (including non-pictures and add a picture of it in iml
    If oShape.Type = 13 Then 'if is picture
        If Not PictureKeyExists(oShape.TopLeftCell.Address, iml) Then 'find if picture key exists, if not add it
            oShape.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap 'copy shape to clipboard
            iml.ListImages.Add 3, oShape.TopLeftCell.Address, PastePicture(xlBitmap) 'add a picture of the clipboard contents to iml with key = to shapes top left corner cell address
            'NOTE: eventhough the index is set to 3 the actual index of the pictures gets incremented automatically
        Else 'if yes report to user and don't add it
            MsgBox "More than one image in cell " & oShape.TopLeftCell.Address & "." & Chr(13) & _
                "Only one will be used."
        End If
    End If
Next
'set TreeView1 formats etc.
With TreeView1
    Set .ImageList = iml
    .Indentation = 14
    .LabelEdit = tvwManual
    .HideSelection = False
    .CheckBoxes = True
    .Style = tvwTreelinesPlusMinusPictureText
    .BorderStyle = ccFixedSingle
End With
'populate TreeView1
With TreeView1.Nodes
    .Clear
    Set oNode = .Add(, , "Root", "Root Node") 'add root node; key = "Root"
    oNode.Expanded = True
    oNode.EnsureVisible
    'look up all cells from A2 to last cell with content in it and add it to TreeView1
    For Each oCell In Sheets(oSheet).Range(oDataColumn & oInitialDataRow, Sheets(oSheet).Range(oDataColumn & "65536").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        'find if parent exists
        Set oParent = Nothing
        For Each oNode In TreeView1.Nodes
            If oNode.Text = oCell.Offset(0, oParentColumnOffset).Value Then
                Set oParent = oNode
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        'find if picture exists, if yes use it, if not use "RED"
        If PictureKeyExists(oCell.Offset(0, oImageColumnOffset).Address, iml) Then
            oImage = oCell.Offset(0, oImageColumnOffset).Address
            Else
            oImage = "red"
        End If
        'add node
        If oParent Is Nothing Then 'if parent not found add as child to root; key = name
            Set oNode = .Add("Root", tvwChild, oCell.Value, oCell.Value, oImage)
            oNode.Expanded = False
        Else 'add as child to parent found previously; key = name concatenated to parent node key
            Set oNode = .Add(oParent.Key, tvwChild, oParent.Key & "|" & oCell.Value, oCell.Value, oImage)
            oNode.Expanded = False
        End If
    Next
End With
End Sub

Function PictureKeyExists(oKey As String, oImageList As ImageList) As Boolean

'Author: Paulo Mendonça 29/August/2014 ppmendonca@hotmail.com

Dim oPicture As ListImage
PictureKeyExists = False
For Each oPicture In oImageList.ListImages
    If oPicture.Key = oKey Then
        PictureKeyExists = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a UserForm? If so here is a suggestion or more of a workaround to your issue.

Why have the images in your worksheet to then try and load them in the form? Maybe try having them in the UserForm in the first place, here is how.

Create a frame on your userform:
[Frame http://im88.gulfup.com/Moy8I6.png](http://im88.gulfup.com/Moy8I6.png)

Set the visible property of the frame to "**False**":
[Visible http://im88.gulfup.com/sAIQqh.png](http://im88.gulfup.com/sAIQqh.png)

Insert your images by adding a picture control and loading the images, you can add as many images as you need:
[Images http://im88.gulfup.com/oas0EQ.png](http://im88.gulfup.com/oas0EQ.png)

Name the images:
[Name http://im88.gulfup.com/cIO317.png](http://im88.gulfup.com/cIO317.png)

Drag all the images one over the other into the frame, (you can then move the frame into a corner so it doesn't bother you:

[Drag http://im88.gulfup.com/1fOSut.png](http://im88.gulfup.com/1fOSut.png)
[Move Away http://im88.gulfup.com/Q1fzKd.png](http://im88.gulfup.com/Q1fzKd.png)

Next create a picture control, this is what you will use to display the picture based on a selection:

[Form View http://im88.gulfup.com/X1UVRB.png](http://im88.gulfup.com/X1UVRB.png)

In this example, I am going to use a combobox for the selection. Now insert the below code in to the form which is pretty straight forward:

```
    Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    ' Image1 is the name of the created picture control
    UserForm3.Controls.Item("Image1").Picture = UserForm3.Controls.Item(UserForm3.ComboBox1.Value).Picture 

    End Sub

    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    UserForm3.ComboBox1.AddItem "Argentina"
    UserForm3.ComboBox1.AddItem "Brazil"
    UserForm3.ComboBox1.AddItem "Chile"

    End Sub
```

As you will see, the frame with the pictures is Hidden, and the image is changing inside the picture control based on a selection:

[Result http://im88.gulfup.com/MSqyHF.png](http://im88.gulfup.com/MSqyHF.png)

I think it's the better way to go as opposed to exporting the images from the worksheet to  a Temp folder and then loading them back into the picture controls.

Comment: How are you loading the images into the image control from the worksheet?

Comment: @SiddharthRout I am not. I am loading them from the drive: http://im75.gulfup.com/XozBxM.png Then I put them all in a Frame as described above and the Frame's Visible property is set as "False". Using this approach they become embedded in the userform as opposed to the having them in the worksheet in the first place. Then they can be displayed using the code in another control as needed  :)

Comment: Yes that would have worked beautifully if there were few and fixed images :) But like OP mentioned `CaptainABC's approach requires I load the pictures at design time, but that is not possible because the users will populate the workheet with their own images and data afterwards. –`

Comment: However + 1 for the efforts :)