# Insert picture/icon in or over a cell

Tags: vba, excel

I hope I make this clear:

I have a loop that copies some hyperlinks in specific cells (they come from a document list with the file path, document name, etc stored in another sheet).

I would like to have an icon next to the hyperlink that indicates if it will open a word document, a folder, etc. In the document list, I can put an indicator in the column next to the hyperlink (1 for word doc, 2 for folder, etc) so that depending on the case, the right icon gets sent next to the right type of document hyperlink.

I have managed to do it by simply inserting shapes (blue rectangle for word doc, green for folder) but I'd like to have a more descriptive symbol (like a specific FaceID maybe?). Here is my code (dumbed down for simplicity):

```
Sub Icons()
Dim i As Integer
Dim sh As Object
'Only loops through A1:A5 for simplicity
'Looks at the associated indicator located in the previous sheet
'Assigns a shape depending if it is 1 or 2
For i = 1 To 5
    If Feuil1.Range("A" & i) = "1" Then
        Set sh = Feuil2.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, Range("A"& i).Left, Range("A" & i).Top, 15, 15)
    sh.Name = "WordDocIcon" & i
    sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 220, 220)
End If

If Feuil1Range("A" & i) = "2" Then
        'It is easy to do when inserting a given msoShape, but I want something else!
    Set sh = Feuil2.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, Range("A" & i).Left, Range("A" & i).Top, 15, 15)
    sh.Name = "FolderIcon" & i
    sh.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(100, 100, 0)
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I can show you how to insert actual word/folder icons but wouldn't a simple way would be to show it as text in the next column? or as a matter of fact color the next cell?

Comment: No, as space is very limited. I am doing an interactive map of a heavy work process, and the file names appear under the process in which they will be used. Processes follow each other like a path (they are buttons leading elsewhere). I'd like to have the icon next to the document name (which is a hyperlink, by the way) so users will know what they open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to my comments, Here is how you can insert pictures and position them in say Column B. I would still say that typing "Word" or "Folder" in Column B and then coloring the cell would be much simpler :)

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim picWord As String
    Dim picFolder As String
    Dim Shp As Shape
    Dim i As Long

    picWord = "C:\Users\Siddharth\Desktop\Word.Jpg"
    picFolder = "C:\Users\Siddharth\Desktop\folder.Jpg"

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1")

    With ws
        For i = 1 To 5
            If .Range("A" & i) = "1" Then
                With .Pictures.Insert(picWord)
                    With .ShapeRange
                        .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                        .Width = ws.Range("B" & i).Width
                        .Height = ws.Range("B" & i).Height
                    End With
                    .Left = ws.Range("B" & i).Left
                    .Top = ws.Range("B" & i).Top
                    .Placement = 1
                    .PrintObject = True
                End With
            ElseIf .Range("A" & i) = "2" Then
                With .Pictures.Insert(picFolder)
                    With .ShapeRange
                        .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                        .Width = ws.Range("B" & i).Width
                        .Height = ws.Range("B" & i).Height
                    End With
                    .Left = ws.Range("B" & i).Left
                    .Top = ws.Range("B" & i).Top
                    .Placement = 1
                    .PrintObject = True
                End With
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

I used the following pictures. You can download these or use whatever you like.

[image]
[image]

When you run the above code, you will get this kind of output

[image]

Comment: I think that would work very well for my computer, but I am designing a program that will be used by 20+ people, will they all need to have the picture saved at that exact path? If so, that would be problematic. That's why I wanted to use a FaceID, but if there is a way to work around it, I would appreciate to know how!
Thanks!

Comment: Yes there is a workaround :) See [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782394/pop-up-the-excel-statusbar/10787496#10787496). I have also given a link for the sample file. See how I am using the picture from the excel sheet and reinserting it.