# How to use ProgressBar Control 6.0 for a VBA Userform sub

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, loading

I have trouble getting to understand how to use the ProgressBar Control in Word VBA. Most tutorials deal with calculation and insertion into Excel cells. I have a commandbutton in my userform executing **A LOT** of file insertion and user input textbox insertion to my word document. (`selection.insertfile:""` and `.Bookmarks("").Range.Text`)

I have inserted the ProgressBar Control right on the userform itself.

Is there an easy way to track the progress of the code run? Something along the lines of:

```
Private Sub Commandbutton1_Click()

ProgressBar1 Start (0%)

'Do stuff:
selection.insertfile:""
selection.insertfile:""
.Bookmarks("").Range.Text
.Bookmarks("").Range.Text
etc.
etc.

Progressbar1 Finish (100%)
Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: You might find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10787496/2521004) interesting.