# Adding Picture to Userform from Sheet on initialize

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a script that will allow me to load pictures contained in my workbook into my `userform` dynamically in an attempt to make the workbook completely portable. I've come up with the following that seems to work but there is one line which I don't understand why it doesn't work without. If I remove the line `.ChartArea.Select` the image won't load. However, If I leave it in it works fine. Ideally I'd like to remove it so I can avoid using a pointless `Select`. Can anyone explain?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.Picture = LoadPicture(Filename:=ExportMyPicture(Sheet1.Pictures(1)))
    Me.PictureSizeMode = fmPictureSizeModeZoom
End Sub


Private Function ExportMyPicture(pic As Picture) As String
    Dim fName As String

    fName = Environ("Temp") & "/" & pic.Name & ".bmp"

    With pic.Parent.ChartObjects.Add(50, 40, pic.ShapeRange.Width, pic.ShapeRange.Height)
        .Border.LineStyle = 0

        pic.Copy

        With .Chart
            ' Removing the following line stops the picture from loading
            .ChartArea.Select
            .Paste
            If .Export(Filename:=fName, filtername:="bmp") Then
                ExportMyPicture = fName
            End If
        End With
        .Delete
    End With
End Function
```

Demo:

[image: Demo]

Using this png:
[image]
url: SO converts it to a jpg
http://pngimg.com/uploads/cat/cat_PNG50497.png

---

**Picture by Mikku**

[image]

Comment: Did you try `.ChartArea.Paste` ?

Comment: @Mikku I get an 'Object doesn't support this property or method' error using that

Comment: I tried the code with and without line. It works smoothly.

Comment: @Mikku Interesting can you try with the png I have linked to? Have updated my question with a demo and url to a test image

Comment: Added my Version with your Png

Comment: @Mikku - thanks. It works if I step through it but not if I run it.....I wonder if it is some delay from the file being created

Comment: Added a 5 second delay - nothing changed on run

Comment: Does invoking `DoEvents` twice instead of `.ChartArea.Select` work? The `.Select` might not be pointless, if it kicks Excel where it hurts enough to wake up and realize the OLE object ought to be in the clipboard by now.

Comment: @Mikku F8-stepping through the code probably makes a difference, if it's a timing issue. That said the gif with the picture showing up on the form is making the post confusing.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Same results unfortunately. It might not be pointless but I'd prefer to reference it explicitly instead of using a `Select` or at least understand why it is needed. Don't seem to be able to though

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782394/pop-up-the-excel-statusbar/10787496#10787496

Comment: See the above link. I have used the pie images from the sheet and shown them in the userform...

Comment: @SiddharthRout looks good but unfortunately I cant use ‘user32’ api calls. My IT department have blocked them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has all looks of a timing issue, which *could* be a bug in how the OLE object is implementing its `.Copy` method; the `.Select` call gives it the kick it needs to get back on track.

Comments are there to say *why* we do things. This is one of these cases where commenting is simply the best possible thing to do... your comment isn't bad at all - it explains *why*, not *what* - and that is exactly what we want comments to say.

> ```
> ' Removing the following line stops the picture from loading
> .ChartArea.Select
> ```

Some alternatives:

```
.ChartArea.Select ' Picture.Copy timing issue; this prevents subsequent .Paste from being no-op.
```

```
.ChartArea.Select ' HERE BE DRAGONS! Remove this instruction and you'll break the .Paste!
```

Comment: I've accepted this as an answer as it is probably the closest to poking at the root cause of it. Bit frustrating but at least it works overall. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it may be a timing issue.  If you pause the macro for a few seconds after copying the picture to the clipboard, it creates a file with the image and loads it successfully.  However, `.ChartArea.Select` seems to be a good workaround. In any case, if you want to try pausing the macro, here's an example...

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.Picture = LoadPicture(Filename:=ExportMyPicture(Sheet1.Pictures(1)))
    Me.PictureSizeMode = fmPictureSizeModeZoom
End Sub

Private Function ExportMyPicture(pic As Picture) As String
    Dim fName As String

    fName = Environ("Temp") & "/" & pic.Name & ".bmp"

    With pic.Parent.ChartObjects.Add(50, 40, pic.ShapeRange.Width, pic.ShapeRange.Height)
        .Border.LineStyle = 0

        pic.Copy

        PauseMacro

        With .Chart
            .Paste
            If .Export(Filename:=fName, filtername:="bmp") Then
                ExportMyPicture = fName
            End If
        End With
        .Delete
    End With
End Function

Private Sub PauseMacro()

    Dim StartTime As Single

    StartTime = Timer
    Do Until Timer > StartTime + 3 'seconds delay
        DoEvents
    Loop

End Sub
```

Note that a 1 second delay seems to work as well, but maybe best to keep it at a 3 second delay just in case.