# Excel: how to show a dialog on start calculation and hide at the end?

Tags: excel, vba

I've an Excel dashboard with some VBA code in the hood. This VBA do some query to a db , and do some calculation.

Can you suggest me which is the event where to show dialog (like "OnStartCalculate") and which is the event to hide my dialog (like "OnEndCalculate") ?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps show a [progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782394/pop-up-the-excel-statusbar)

Answer (score 1):

You should include your code and what you've tried so far.
However, here are a possible solution to your problem:

```
    Sub StatusBarUpdate()
    
      With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .StatusBar = "Calculation in progress."
      End With
    
    'All of your current code goes here. You set the statusbar text above, and run your code. 
    'After your code has run, you turn off the statusbar and reset the calculation mode.
    
      With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .StatusBar = False
      End With
    
    End Sub
```

**Why do I use status bar, rather than a message box?**

There is no easy way to use message box to accomplish the same thing as above. But, it is quite easy to change the text of the status bare in the lower left corner of your application. This is what above code snippet does.

Comment: The above should work. If you want it more prominent, you could use a UserForm to display this message.

Answer (score 0):

Do the work within the status form.  This gives you the option of including a cancel button.  Design a form with the message you want (called e.g. frmStatus).
frmStatus should contain the following code

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    DoEvents
    DoCalculation
    Unload Me
End Sub

Sub DoCalculation()
    ' Do your database stuff
End Sub
```

When you want to perform the calculation simply call

```
frmStatus.Show vbModal
```